# Bash Script execute command with argument

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to build a new hosting server and migrate over 50+ sites. I need to run this command to build each site using RT Easy Engine.

```
sudo ee domain.com --php
```

I have created a txt file with the domains and I can get it to loop through no problem.

```
array=()
# Read the file in parameter and fill the array named "array"

getArray() {
    i=0
    while read line # Read a line
    do
        array[i]=$line # Put it into the array
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done < $1
}

getArray "domains.txt"

for e in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo $e

done
```

I change the for loop to

```
echo "sudo ee " $e
```

Works OK. get `sudo ee domain.com`

How do I add the `--php` on the end and execute?

everytime I add it, I get

```
--phpe domain.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just try this:

```
sed 's/\r//g' domains.txt | while read domain; do
    sudo ee "$domain" --php
done
```

This will read every line and store it in a variable `domain`, which you can call however you like.

Edit: It may be useful to execute `sudo -i` first if your root permission runs out during execution (don't know how long the command runs).

Edit2: Added carriage return removal per request.

Comment: it appears to be much closer but I now getting this output. 
sudo ee $'domain.com\r' --php

so close, thanks for the quick reply. Any further ideas?

Comment: mrwilde, the file you are running seems to be in Windows format... Convert it to Unix format

Comment: Davide is right, you could consider the program `unix2dos` too but `sed` is easier in my opinion since you don't need to install anything.

Comment: Thankyou, that was painful and it really shouldn't have been.